# Concatenating multiple fastq files and renaming to parent folder

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fastq

Currently, I have genome sequencing data as fq.gz files and each sample consists of a folder titled with the sample name containing 2-8 pairs of forward and reverse reads. I would like to concatenate all of the forward and reverse files into one forward and one reverse file for each sample while maintaining pair order.

My data are organized as follows:

```
/ParentFolder/SampleA/V549_1.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleA/V549_2.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleA/V550_1.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleA/V550_2.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleB/V588_1.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleB/V588_2.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleB/V599_1.fq.gz
/ParentFolder/SampleB/V599_2.fq.gz
```

In order to concatenate the files, I tried the following:

```
ls *_1.fq.gz | sort | xargs cat > SampleA_1.fq.gz
ls *_2.fq.gz | sort | xargs cat > SampleA_2.fq.gz
```

This works for one sample folder, however, since I have many dozens of samples, I would like to write a bash script to accomplish this across all my samples and rename the concatenated files to name of their parent folder. I am still learning but I am a bit lost, I would greatly appreciate any help with this problem.

I have attempted the following, without success:

```
for i in $(find ./ -type f -name "*.fq.gz"; done | sort | uniq)
do echo "Merging 1"
cat "$i"*_1.fq.gz > "$i"CG1-1_1.fq.gz
```

Thank you for any input/advice/solutions.

Comment: Hi Helen, welcome to StackOverflow! I think it will be more clear if you put more details of the expected output you desire. I recommend your a short read of our guides here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add an [mcve], that will help a log figure out the details of your question.

Comment: Can we assume you will only have files `_1` and `_2` ?  So the final result is one file `_1` and one `_2` for each sample directory?  Assume we know nothing of your requirements (which we don't).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following logic:

- for each suffix (_1, _2):

  - Find all the fq.gz files
  - Extract list of folders
  - For each folder
  - Merge all the containing 'fq' files into new 'all.FOLDER.fq.gz'

```
p=pp
for suffix in 1 2 ; do
    # Find all dirs containing suffix files.
    dirs=$(printf '%s\n' $p/*/*_$suffix.fq.gz | sed 's:/[^/]*$::' | uniq)
    for d in $dirs ; do
        # Merge, and store in parent.
        (cd $d ; cat *_${suffix}.fq.gz > ../${d##*/}_${suffix}.fq.gz)
    done
done
```

Notes:

- code assume no special characters in folder names.
- More compact files will be created if the merge process will uncompressed the original data, and re-compress. (gzcat *.gz